# Convert JsonObject to pojo efficiently with JSON-B 1.0 (e.g. Yasson, Java EE 8)

Tags: json, jsonp, java-ee-8, jsonb-api, yasson

A JsonObject can be transformed into it's corresponding class instance via:

`Pojo pojo = JsonbBuilder.create().fromJson(jsonObject.toString(), Pojo.class)`

However, it seems to be inefficient to use `jsonObject.toString()` as a String is an other intermediate representation, that contains the same information. I need to transform the jsonObject before the object binding. So is there a more efficient way to achieve the binding from a JsonObject?

(Note I want to implement with Java EE 8 standards, so Gson and Jackson is not an option, but may be concepts of it). There is currently not answer in the [Yasson](https://github.com/eclipse-ee4j/yasson/issues/259) group so hopefully, someone finds this. Michael Schnell also proposed a [JsonStructure](https://github.com/eclipse-ee4j/jsonb-api/issues/111) binding, but there is no solution yet too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not possible with the JSON-B 1.0 standard to convert JSON-P object <--> POJO. However, enough people have asked for it that it's certainly something we will consider for the next version of JSON-B.

In the meantime, converting to String or using a custom adapter is your best option.

**If you are concerned about performance with JSON-B**, the #1 thing you can do to improve JSON-B performance is cache the instance of `Jsonb`, namely, don't call `JsonbBuilder.create()` each time you need to call to/fromJson, because all of the annotation scanning and class parsing happens upon creation of the `Jsonb` instance.

**Update (June 2019):**
Although there is still no JSON-B standard way of doing this, the JSON-B reference implementation, Eclipse Yasson, has added support for this on the `org.eclipse.yasson.YassonJsonb` interface in [this PR](https://github.com/eclipse-ee4j/yasson/pull/262/files). Hopefully this function will get included in the next version of the JSON-B spec.

Comment: Great to know both hints! So I guess, it's not trivial and I shouldn't try it by myself.

Comment: updated my original answer to indicate that this is now possible with Yasson API (but still not JSON-B spec standard)